# Simple Probability problem with circle and triangle

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

A clock is hanging on the wall and has diameter 6cm. An isosceles triangle is inscribed with the vertices touching the rim of the clock at 9:00, 12:00, and 3:00. If a dart is thrown at the clock, assuming it's equally as likely to hit anywhere in the clock and it will definitely hit the clock, what's the probability it lands inside the triangle?

I've found that the area of the circle is 9pi and that of the triangle is 9.
Therefore the Probability to be in the triangle is 1/pi and the probability it lands outside the triangle is 1-1/pi. 
Can somebody confirm that I have it right?

Comment: Yes, your solution looks correct to me.